# Mixing C# and HTML Helper tags

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I need to use `IF-ELSE` conditions to check if the person is named `Perry`. If so, i need to execute the `IF` statement, or else if the person name isn't `Perry` then i will execute the else block.

Even-though they say we could mix `C#` with `HTML helper` tags, i am not able to use the `IF-ELSE` condition as this. The `IF-ELSE` gets displayed as text. How can i correct my code ?

```
if(person == "Perry") 
{
    <div class="content">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Go", "MyPro", new { }, FormMethod.Post, new { }))
    {
         @Html.TextBoxFor(mod => mod.id, new { id = "nameid" }) 
         <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /> 
         <input type="submit" value="send" class="send"/>    
        </div>
   }
}else {
    <div class="content1">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Come", "MyPro", new { }, FormMethod.Post, new { }))
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(mod => mod.id, new { id = "schoolid" }) 
            <input type="submit" value="Send School" class="submitschool"/>
        }
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put `@` before C# code in HTML tags, that is all...

```
@{var person = "text";}

@if(person == "Perry") 
{
    <div class="content">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Go", "MyPro", new { }, FormMethod.Post, new { }))
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(mod => mod.id, new { id = "nameid" }) 
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /> 
            <input type="submit" value="send" class="send"/>    
        }
    </div>
}
else 
{
    <div class="content1">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Come", "MyPro", new { }, FormMethod.Post, new { }))
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(mod => mod.id, new { id = "schoolid" }) 
            <input type="submit" value="Send School" class="submitschool"/>
        }
    </div>
}
```

[RAZOR SYNTAX EXAMPLES](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx)

Comment: What if i want to create a variable outside the IF statement. is it @var n =""; because this didn't work.

Comment: if-else is behaving single block, so you dont need to use brackets.

Comment: check [HERE](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Need to prepend an `@` in front of the `if`, otherwise the Razor view engine doesn't know you want to switch to "code mode".

Comment: How should i create a variable outside the if statement. @var something="" didn't work